# Chart.js simple line graph

Tags: javascript, angular, charts

I have a problem with simple chart.js graph in angular

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12"><strong>Výškový profil</strong></div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <canvas baseChart
            [datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [chartType]="'line'"
            [colors]="lineChartColors"
            [legend]="false"
    ></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: there is a bootstrap container in the page so grid system is fine

**Typescript**

```
public barChartOptions:any = {
    chartType: 'line',
    legend: false,
    responsive: true,
};
public barChartLabels:string[];

public barChartData:any[] = [{data:[10,200,30,40]}];

public lineChartColors:Array<any> = [
    {
        backgroundColor: '#23CE6B',
        borderColor: '#23CE6B'
    }
];
```

The problem is, If i can this sample (the data are just dummy they will be loaded from API) I get this result

[image]

And thats not what I've expected.

There are just 2 points from 4 (from 10 do 200).
**How can I modify this to show whole data graph?**

Plus one question **can I put the label for Y axis?** (on the left side of the numbers)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ChartJS 2.0` or above, you can customize your graph by modifying the `scales` property in the options object:

```
options = {
    scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'Your Y axis label'
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Depending on your version, you might want to set the option:
`bezierCurve: false` or `tension: 0` I have the feeling your points are being plotted but your curve is too round and filled with a background color that you cannot tell.

Comment: Thanks for help with that Y axis label. Works like charm. I figured out I need to have as many labels as data. Is there any possibility NOT to have to set labels? So data will be spread all over graph from 0 to 100% of data length?

Comment: `Chartjs` won't support the automatic 0 to 100%, it's something you need to manage on your own, that means, prepare your data and send it in the desired format to your data object.